# Is it possible to replicate behavior of the "exists" method using pattern matching in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Suppose I have a `Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and I want to know if value "4" exists in it. I want to know if it is possible to find and extract the answer **only using pattern matching**.

```scala
Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) match {
  case Seq(_, 4, _*) => true
  case _ => false
}
```

match clauses like this only works if the position of our specified value is known. I am curious to know if it is possible to do this in Scala, I am new to Scala and not completely familiar with its syntax and features.

obviously using the if gaurd is not helpful because it does not allow extracting the value to a variable.

you may ask why it is even important and why not use current existing `exists` or `filter` methods. Imagine the case below.

```scala
case class Score(eventName: String, amount: Integer)
case class Person(name: String, scores: Seq[Score])
```

suppose I have a collection of `Person`s and I want to find the highest score for a certain event. a person may have a score for that event or may not.

```scala
persons.collect({
          case x @ _ if x.scores.exists(_.eventName == "event1") =>
            x.scores.find(_.eventName == "event1").get.amount
        }).max
```

the problem is that the filter on `eventName` is processed two times.
I know it is possible to do this using `filter` and `map` with mutiple iterations. but I am interested to know if there is a solution using pattern matching, with pattern matching you can find and extract the value to a variable at the same time.

Comment: there is no way currently to introduce term inside guard part of pattern matching (I mean `if ...`). I was looking for something like that but without luck. I've some workarounds but they are rather ugly one, and will fail in some configurations.

Comment: Also Extractor objects are kind of useless here. https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html. You'll need to create such extractor for each case independently before `case ...` clausule. It means it will not be never handy tool in such cases :(.

Comment: Please don't change the question after people have answered it.

Comment: @Tim the question is sill the same and not answered. people were focusing too much on the sample.

Comment: People answered this question: "I am interested to know if there is a solution using pattern matching, with pattern matching you can find and extract the value to a variable at the same time".
If that is not the question you meant to ask then it might be better to create a new post with the question that you actually want to ask rather than deleting that question from this post.

Comment: I am looking to a general answer and I used an example to further clarify. the big title at the top of the page is "Is it possible to replicate behavior of the “exists” method using pattern matching in Scala?". anyway, using unapply seems to be the closest solution so far.

Comment: 'unapply' is the underlying mechanism for pattern matching (along with runtime type checking), so that is certainly the first place to look if you want to understand what is possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom matcher with an `unapply` method:

```
case class EventScore(eventName: String) {
  def unapply(person: Person): Option[Int] =
    person.scores.collectFirst { case s if s.eventName == eventName => s.amount }
}

val score = EventScore("event1")

persons.collect({
  case score(amount) => amount
}).max
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do it by pattern matching inside a recursive method but I think this is all you need:

```
persons.flatMap(_.scores.filter(_.eventName == "ev1")
                        .map(_.amount))
       .maxOption
       .getOrElse(0)
```

Or the prettier `for` comprehension:

```
(for {
  person <- persons
  score <- person.scores
  if score.eventName == "ev1"
} yield score.amount).maxOption.getOrElse(0)
```

---

```
//using only pattern matching
def has(xs: Seq[Int], target: Int) : Boolean = xs match {
  case Seq()                => false
  case Seq(`target`, _ @_*) => true
  case Seq(_, tl @_*)       => has(tl, target)
}
```

testing:

```
has(List(2,4,5,11,44,66), 11)  //true
has(List(2,4,5,11,44,66), 12)  //false
has(List(2,4,5,11,44,66), 66)  //true
```

Comment: I know it is possible using filter and map. I want to know if there are ways to do it using only pattern-matching

Answer (score 1):

There is no way currently to introduce term inside guard part of pattern matching (I mean `if ...` part). I was looking for something like that but without luck.

In your example tho you don't need it. Few words about example:

- Using two brackets is not necessary `collect({..})`.
- `@ _` in case is not necessary either
- `.max` will blow on empty collection. It is especially risky with `collect`

Here is my proposition:

```scala
persons.map { 
  case x => x.scores.find(_.eventName == "event1").getOrElse(0) 
}.max
```